# google developer geo chart and DAO objects

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I saw this link from google...
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

In this code..

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Germany', 200],
          ['United States', 300],
          ['Brazil', 400],
          ['Canada', 500],
          ['France', 600],
          ['RU', 700]
        ]);

        var options = {};

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

is it possible to replace the contents of "function drawRegionsMap()"
with object coming from servelet and DAO?

im just curious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use google charts in my JSP projects all the time. Basically the way I get my data in the "function draw...()" is to generate the javascript server side containing all my own data, then sending it off to the JSP page in a normal java String object inserting it like this"

```
<script type="javascript/text"><%= youGeneratedJs %></script>
```

That way your generated javascript will run once you JSP page runs. It's a difficult work around but if you look [here](http://deangrobler.com/?p=125) you'll get a better understanding of how I go about getting data from my server, generating the google-chart script server side, and then running it in my JSP page...

Hope this helped!